# eclipse deleted app file contents

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been working on an app at work using eclipse. The files were saved on my external hard drive and I've now brought it home to work on. The project wouldn't show up in the workspace so I tried to import the project. All the files are there but have no contents in any file. **** hell!

My questions being :

1. can i get these back
2. if not, I was testing through my SGS3 so it is installed on my phone, can I get my files back that way?

regards

Comment: How did you saved your files from Eclipse to Hard Drive ? is SGS3 your H.D. ?

Comment: My files/project is on a separate external harddrive. Eclipse is also on there. I just use my SGS3 instead of the AVD

Comment: You mean that you're testing directly on your _Samsung Galaxy S3_ rather than _emulating_ using an _Virtual Device_ ? if it is right can you please edit your post.

Comment: I'm not being funny but yes, you're right and that is in the question.
`I was testing through my SGS3 so it is installed on my phone`

Comment: I just faced a similar problem. The contents of the files in my Android Application Project disappeared after I imported it into Eclipse as "Android Project from Existing Code". Coincidentally, the files were also saved in my external hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you installed on your *Samsung Galaxy S3* is a deployable app **.apk**. You can get only the .apk file, not your source files or Eclipse project configs.

Comment: Can you tell me why eclipse has wiped the contents of my files?

Comment: Well the first thing to do is to restart your IDE, does it work now ? if not can you please be more precise about the files you imported to Eclipse ?

Comment: I've looked on my EHD, all files are 0kb, I've not pressed save or anything like that. The whole file structure is intact, just wiped clean! I looked on the project explorer, nothing, so right clicked "import" -> "android" -> "Existing code into workspace"... thats it!

Comment: Sorry, you cannot get back the content of your files. because the creation of the files _Succeeded_ but the _copy_ of the content to EHD did not.